# mongodb concurrency on inserting document

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

Says we currently have two collections: `Teachers` and `Students`, we limit each teacher can only owns up to **30** students, surely I have already set a reference-key like `studentsId`, `teachersId` on each document.

When I'm about to create a new Student, how can I make sure I only create it when the specify teacher has less than 30 students?

```
// get students count under specify teacher
const StudentNums = await Teachers.findById(1234).studentsId.length;
if (StudentNums < 30) /* create student */
```

(above code is written JS)

undoubtedly above code would fail when concurrency, cause mongodb share read locks, any ideas? tks in advance.

Comment: Why not using callback ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel If you mean we get teacher's students count and then create one do it the callback way, I would say here we are talking abt threads, several threads runs a snippet of code at the same time then they get same students count and create resources which may cause incorrect logic.

Comment: @BertrandMartel besides, [async/await](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) syntax doesnt change the callback work theory in depth, you can treat it as a syntax sugar, write like sync but works async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling anything related to concurrency, why not just check if your teacher can accomodate any more students ? You can check and update in a single operation to ensure atomicity.

It essentially boils down to adding student length check in find query like below :

```
teachers.update({id: 1, '$where': 'this.students.length < 8'}, {'$push': {students: 8}}
```

Added a test case below:

```
 const mongodb = require('mongodb')
 const mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

 mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stackoverflow', function (err, db) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(`DB connect error ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
   } else {
     const teachers = db.collection('teachers')
     let doc = {id: 1, name: 'Ms Anderson', students: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], subject: 'Matrix'}
     teachers.insert(doc, {w: 1}, function (err, result) {
       console.log(`insert error ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
       console.log(`insert result : ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
//Check the $where parameter, it will return only if student array has size less than 8
       teachers.update({id: 1, '$where': 'this.students.length < 8'}, {'$push': {students: 8}}, {w: 1}, function (err, result) {
         console.log(`update error ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
         console.log(`update result : ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
       })
     })
   }
 })
```

`result` is 1 if document is updated else 0.

Comment: I read the mongodb docs and realized there did exist such `$where: { this.xxx }` syntax, it just fits my need. However, I still first have to create a student then push it to corresponding teacher otherwise destroy the newly created record, is there a way avoid this operation?

Comment: you can just delete the student record afterwards no ?

Comment: absolutely, but when there are a thousands of requests, thousands of records will be created, sure we can use rate-limit/load-balancing, but just for curiosity, can we avoid this? I know this is a little beyond this topic, I just want to figure out is there a better way, tks

Comment: maybe you can actually query the teacher document and check its length and then create a student. Still you will add the studentRef in teacher with your where clause to be totally safe atomic wise. This way after 30 students rest 970 students won't be even created in mongodb

Comment: Well, even with the where clause it's still a query, which means a read operation, mongodb shares read lock, other threads can also read student length at the same time, here am I misunderstanding your opinion on `studentRef with where clause` ?

Comment: the update statement is atomic, so the where clause and write operation are one shot thing. It's not the case that 2 separate update queries will get length of 29 and then will add students to collection. One will get 29 and other will get it as 30. I think mongo doc mentions this.

Comment: So far above answer is enough to satisfy this question, I'll accept it first. As in mongo doc, mongo uses read/write lock, read lock is shared as the [doc mentioned](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply standard [Optimistic lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) on application level.

Assuming a document in teacher collection has following fields:

```
db.teachers.insert({
    _id: 1234,
    students: [12,34],
    version: 8
});
```

Where `_id` and `students` are object's payload, and `version` is an internal field for concurrency control. The update in the question may look like following:

```
var teacher = db.teachers.findById(1234);

if(teacher.students.length < 30) {
    var res = db.teachers.update({_id: 1234, version: teacher.version}, {$push: {students: 56}, $inc: {version: 1}});
}

if(res.nModified < 1) {
    // apply retry logic
}
```

If the concurrent update happened, version of the document in the database won't match the query part of the update, which will result with 0 documents updated.

Comment: Yeah it's a common way doing such thing, almost forgot it. As I saw @Sikorski 's answer below without introduce new field, I would probably choose his, what's your saying?

Comment: That's matter of taste. I tend to avoid hrardcoding business logic into queries, as less flexible, but if you have no intention to abstract concurrency control, that's doesn't matter. `$where` requires javascript to be executed on each document, and in general case is considered slow, but in this case that's okay, since we filter collection by id. All in all, it's a good way to resolve the problem without introducing new properties.

Comment: actually we have a long talk abt concurrency on read/write lock below, take a look if you r interested in :D