# Node.js Mongodb Two bookings on same time from two different users. only one can book

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently in my application, users can make a booking for time XYZ, assuming that time XYZ is available. Suppose that another user is also booking for XYZ at the same time as the first user. I want to ensure that if they hit the particular API at the same time only one can have time XYZ and not both. Currently, when a user books a time, I first check my database to see if there is any booking for this particular time, and if there isn't the user gets that time. How can I make sure that if two users book at once, only one gets that time?

Comment: in your mongo update check if booking has not been already made. something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316688/mongodb-concurrency-on-inserting-document/43318965

Comment: I am checking it and it is working fine on that condition. what if two people making a booking request for same time on which there is no booking. then how can I achieve that only one booking will be done.

Comment: update is atomic so that won't happen.

Comment: update is atomic yes, but he is not updating the same document... A good way would be to create a unique index on that set, ensuring that only one document has that time range...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique index, something like this:

db.booking.createIndex( { "time": 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true } )